# Compass font-face outputs wrong path to font file

Tags: css, sass, font-face, compass-sass

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt";
  src: url('/css/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

That is the output of my compass code:

```
@include font-face('HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt', font-files('HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf'));
```

I can't seem to get the output url to be either just 'Helvetica......otf' or just 'fonts/Helvetica......otf'.

My directory assets are as followed:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"
fonts_dir = "fonts"
```

I have tried taking off fonts_dir and changing it to "" with no luck

Comment: This issue has been solved. I just needed to change my assets to relative. I had tried this earlier without the same outcome, but for some odd reason it's working now.

Comment: Set `http_fonts_path` maybe. Does it still happen in latest Compass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `http_fonts_path` or `:relative assets, true`. :)

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. Just use URL instead font-files

```
@include font-face('HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt', url('HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you path output is '/css/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf' but you want it to go to '/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf.

Maybe try changing your config.rb file to

```
fonts_dir = "../fonts"
```

I would not recommend using a .otf file for web

I usually use the mixin this way:

```
@include font-face('HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt', font-files(
'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.woff', woff,
'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.ttf', ttf,
'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.svg', svg),
'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.eot');
```