# Compass @font-face can't find font file

Tags: fonts, sass, compass-sass

My compass directory looks something like this:

```
root_of_directory
  sass
    screen.scss
  stylesheets
    fonts
      goudysto.ttf
    screen.css
```

and then the mixin for font-face looks like this:

```
@include font-face("goudysto", font-files("goudysto.ttf", "truetype"));
```

The output in the console says this:

```
GET file:///fonts/goudysto.ttf net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

This is the outputted css

```
    @font-face {
     font-family: "goudysto";
     src: url('/fonts/goudysto.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

*UPDATE -- config.rb *

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
fonts_dir = "stylesheets/fonts"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

Comment: Its prepending the '/' to your URL, which means the font file is not found as it is looking in the root (if you project is in a project folder, then the root is deeper than your project). Have you tried removing the starting '/' ?

Comment: It's adding the starting / automatically. I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: Remove it in the actual CSS file first to see if that solves it, then at least you know what direction the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the fonts_dir in config.rb like this:

```
fonts_dir = "stylesheets/fonts"
```

Edit: Also, as mentioned in the comments, make sure to uncomment `# relative_assets = true` and use relative paths in config.rb ...

Comment: When I moved it to the root directory it comes up with the following. GET file:///fonts/goudysto.ttf?1413956247 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND index.html:1 Seems to be appending numbers to it.

Comment: The appended numbers are just a cache buster - try editing the outputted CSS file first and see if you can make that point to the right place instead of the SASS, then you know whether its a SASS or more general issue.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. After adding the fonts_dir, you restarted compass?

Comment: @somethinghere I removed the slash in the outputted css file and it's found the font. So it's a SASS issue.

Comment: @elbblick I just restarted it. No luck.

Comment: I know this is probably not the best workaround, but couldn't you copy the edited code and keep that in your SASS file instead of using compass' function..? I know, I know, its not as elegant but for font inclusion I usually find it handy to put all the actual necessary outputted CSS in a separate file and then use @import, so your font has its own little file you can edit without SASS. Just saying though...

Comment: Okay. In which directory did you store the config.rb?

Comment: It's in the root directory. In config.rb `http_path = "/"` Could that be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the complete config.rb?

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: Looks quite good to me, but try uncommenting `# relative_assets = true`, as that issue was described here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205134/compass-font-face-outputs-wrong-path-to-font-file)